# Show data that is in BindingList to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, bindinglist

> Solution: Thanks for Nikita Marinosyan. He found solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869568/binding-objects-datagridview-c-sharp)

I have an Excel document. There are columns like fax, email, number and so on.

In program I have a class `Contact`

```
public class Contact
    {
        private List<long> phones;
        private List<long> faxes;
        private List<string> email;
        private List<string> webSite;

        public string PhoneStr
        {
            get
            {
                string s = "";
                for (int i = 0; i  Phones.Count; i++)
                {
                    ;
                    s += Phones[i];
                }
                return s;
            }
        }


        public List<long> Phones
        {
            get
            {
                return phones;
            }

            private set { phones = value; }
        }
    }
```

and same for faxes, emails and website.

So you can see what properties i have here.
Also I have class `Hotel`

```
    public class Hotel
        {

            private Adress adress;

            private Adress legalAdress;

            private Contact contacts;

    public Hotel(Adress adress, Adress legalAdress,
            string phone, string fax, string email, string webSite, string geo)
            {
                this.Geo1 = new Geo(geo);
                this.adress = adress;
                this.LegalAdress = legalAdress;
                Contacts = new Contact(phone, fax, email, webSite);
            }

            public Contact Contacts
            {
                get { return contacts; }
                set { contacts = value; }
            }
```

Now I want to somehow represent this class Hotel to DataGridView
So I have this.

```
BindingList<Hotel> bl=new BindingList<Hotel>();
```

after that I just fill `bl` and bind it to datagridview:

`dataGridView1.DataSource = bl;`

Obviously, It don't show me what i want. `Contact` column looks like it returned base ToString(): [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQpqu.png)

But it's ok for column Adress because class Adress has overriden method ToStrng().

> The main problem here is that i don't even know how to show data of Contact.
>   I want to show it in different columns, not like Adress.

Comment: WPF or WinForms?  If your doing this in WPF, you can create the DataGridView in the XAML and individually bind each column to a property or a property's property in the list that is bound to the DataGridView

Comment: Yea, I know about this features in WPF. But I should design it in WinForms.

Comment: Seems like you are not the first one wondering. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869568/binding-objects-datagridview-c-sharp)