# Datagridview: how to "typeconvert" a property from a list

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, type-conversion

I'm currently trying to fill a common datagridview, as I'm struggling with typeconverting. Here's my scenario:

I have an entity that has a custom enum:

```
public class HistoryItem
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(CommunicationTypeConverter))]
    public virtual CommunicationType TypeOfCommunication { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual string Remark { get; set; }
}

public enum CommunicationType
{
    OutgoingCall,
    OutgoingEmail
}
```

As you can see I already marked the TypeOfCommunication property for typeconverting:

```
public class CommunicationTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is CommunicationType)
        {
            switch((CommunicationType)value)
            {
                case CommunicationType.OutgoingEmail:
                    return "OUTGOING_EMAIL";
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Currently I'm trying to convert the CommunicationType.ToString() string with a custom string.

I already had a read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579170/binding-custom-list-property-to-datagridview) and I know the concept of typeconverting basically (from WPF), but I dont get the link when it comes to bind a list of this history items to my datagridview:

```
IList<HistoryItem> history = _currentCustomer.HistoryItems;
dgvCustomerHistory.DataSource = history;
dgvCustomerHistory.Columns.Add("TypeOfCommunication", "Type");
dgvCustomerHistory.Refresh();
```

My goal is to "replace" the CommunicationType strings with images/icon - just to let you know where I want to go with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, do you want to auto generate the columns in the `DataGridView`? If so, code it like:

```
IList<HistoryItem> history = _currentCustomer.HistoryItems;
dgvCustomerHistory.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvCustomerHistory.DataSource = history;
```

if not, do it like:

```
IList<HistoryItem> history = _currentCustomer.HistoryItems;
dgvCustomerHistory.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.HeaderText = "Communication Type";
column.DataPropertyName = "TypeOfCommunication"; // Name of property
dgvCustomerHistory.Columns.Add(column);

dgvCustomerHistory.DataSource = history;
```

I think you just need to add some more overrides to the `CommunicationTypeConverter`. You only were handling the `ConvertFrom` method, you need to handle the `ConvertTo` method and the `CanConvert` methods.

```
    public class CommunicationTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string)
            {
                switch ((string)value)
                {
                    case "OUTGOING_EMAIL":
                        return CommunicationType.OutgoingEmail;
                    default:
                        return CommunicationType.OutgoingCall;
                }
            }
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                if (value is CommunicationType)
                {
                    switch ((CommunicationType)value)
                    {
                        case CommunicationType.OutgoingEmail:
                            return "OUTGOING_EMAIL";
                        default:
                            return "OUTGOING_CALL";
                    }
                }
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

You can then return images/icons instead of strings. Just make sure you update both the appropriate `Convert` and `CanConvert` sections.