# I need to customize dataGridView1's specific column so whenever that specific column has "1" it has to say "Tamir" and "0" is "Hazır" i'm using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image: The datagridview]

As you can see I'm trying to do the thing that is said on the title. The situation column is the one that I need to write "Tamir" when it is 1 and "Hazır" when it is 0. I'm using an API to put data inside datagridview and I'm using winforms.

I didn't try anything because nothing came to mind.

Here is my PostResponse.cs

```
public class ProductData 
{
    [JsonProperty("type_name")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Situation { get; set; }
    public string Type_Name { get; set; }
    
}

public class ProductDataFeatures 
{
    [JsonProperty("products_type_feature_id")]
    public string Products_Type_Feature_Id { get; set; }
    public string Feature_Name { get; set; }
    public string Feature_Unit_Name { get; set; }
    public string Feature { get; set; }
}
```

here is my form1load

```
public async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var postData = new PostData
            {
                id = 5,
                title = "yeni",
                description = "yenidesc",
                type_name = "yenitype"
            };

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("i_know_what_must_be_here");

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = client.PostAsync("products", content).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var postResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostResponse>(responseContent); //JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PostResponse>(responseContent);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = postResponse.Products;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hata: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you filling the DataGridView? Please show the code.

Comment: Ideas for you to try something. Clean route. Create a model class that shows data the way you want it(in many patterns such a thing may be called ViewModel. Map your model as you have gotten it from the api onto the model as you want it and bind that to the grid. Dirty route. Handle the CellFormatting event, check for the column and in case map the number on the string you want to show (means return it in the Value Property of the EventArgs).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The `ProductData.Situation` is a string, so you can just rewrite it with the values you want before using it as a data source. Or better yet, create a separate type for the UI representation and then map the values from the response to this new type with the appropriate conversion. You could also try using `TypeConverter` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122913/datagridview-how-to-typeconvert-a-property-from-a-list) but I'm not sure how it might interfere with the json deserializer.